# Php: replacing literal and HTML dollar symbol using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm experimenting with `preg_match` and I came up with this line to help me find the first dollar amount on the page:

```
preg_match('/\$(.*)/', $content, $USDmatch);
```

Which works awesome however the site that I'm targeting has this in their source instead of the `$` sign they use `&#36;`. How do I search for that?

Comment: You can't just add quotes?

Comment: Search for the literal `&#36;` then, or convert entities beforehand.

Comment: preg_match('/&#36/', $content, $USDmatch); Like that? because that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Personally - because I am not an expert at regex and by the looks of it, neither are you, run it like this:

```
$result = preg_match("/((\$|&#36;)(\S*))/g", $content, $USDmatch );
```

What does this do? 
Well:

- /((\$|`&#36;`)(\S*))/g
- 1st Capturing group ((\$|`&#36;`)(\S*))
- 2nd Capturing group (\$|`&#36;`)
- 1st Alternative: \$
- \$ matches the character $ literally
- 2nd Alternative: `&#36;`
- `&#36;` matches the characters `&#36;` literally
- 3rd Capturing group (\S*)
- \S* match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
- Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

  - g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

The `/g` modifier is not strictly needed but I added it in here to search for all occurrences, rather than returning on the first. Adapt as required.

so with the above code, and an example below we have:

```
$content = "e gnerij &#36;100 gnerjingeijrn gijern jiner e r $100 begrbrtbtr erh jerng knrj gnrjk "

 $result = preg_match("/((\$|&#36;)(\S*))/g", $content, $USDmatch );
```

from this:
`$result` returns `TRUE`, (two finds, although this is beyond the scope of this use of `Preg_match`)

I strongly recommend using http://www.regex101.com for exploring the cloudy world of Regex.